# ml32i1m.lib and ml64i3m.lib Files

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I have to install a package to use together with MatLab (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6044-mathematica-symbolic-toolbox-for-matlab-version-2-0][1](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6044-mathematica-symbolic-toolbox-for-matlab-version-2-0)) that requires locating files mathlink.h and ml32i1m.lib (or ml64i3m.lib in 64 bits, although I am not 100% sure about this one for 64 bits system).

Apparently I need to have an add-on called Mathlink, but I couldnt find any to install (and neither in my Mathematica system folder). Has it been discontinued? How can I install it or find these files I need?

Thanks.

Comment: If you search google for Matlink, it's the first hit: http://matlink.org/

Comment: @bills Thanks for mentioning it, but I think the OP wants to access Mathematica from MATLAB, not the reverse.  MATLink can only access MATLAB from Mathematica, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

MathLink is the name of a communication protocol for Mathematica and a C API to access this protocol.  All versions of Mathematica come with MathLink.  The relevant files are in the installation directory.

Since version 10, MathLink has been renamed to WSTP and the `ML`-prefixed function names have been changes to `WS`-prefixed ones.  This means that now it's easier to search for documentation using the keyword "WSTP" but if you want to compile an older program you still need to use the libraries that have the `ML` prefix.

To find where all the libraries are, go here: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/WSTPAPI.html  Then click Tutorials in the upper right corner and choose the developer guide for your operating system. It will tell you where to look for these files and how to compile MathLink-based programs.